# How to avoid 'Cannot read write-only property' using bindable constraint on transient

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-3.1

I'm having trouble to bind values using a transient property using grails 3.1.4.

Taking this domain as an example:

```
class Domain {
    Boolean b1
    Boolean b2
    Boolean b3

    void setPropertyList(propertyList) {
        if(propertyList.contains('someValue'))
            this.b1 = true         
    }

    static transients = ['propertyList']

    static constraints = {
        propertyList bindable: true
    }
}
```

I would like to use a specific property (here: `propertyList`) for data binding. This property is available in the data binding source, but not in my domain. So I added a transient and a setter. To include the transient `propertyList` for data binding I added the `bindable`constraint.

The setter `setPropertyList` is called during data binding. The properties of the resulted domain instance has all properties set as expected.
But when I try to save the resulted instance I get the following exception:

```
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Cannot read write-only property: propertyList
    at org.grails.validation.ConstrainedPropertyBuilder.doInvokeMethod(ConstrainedPropertyBuilder.java:74)
```

Looks like grails having some trouble to validate the instance.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some debugging it turns out, that grails couldn't find a type for `propertyList` and so skips the data binding.

Adding a getter helps grails to infer the type.
This avoids the exception.

```
List<String> getPropertyList() {}
```